# How to save cookie on server side in next js through middleware

Tags: javascript, cookies, server, next.js13, react-server-components

following official next js docs i can get cookies on server side using middleware

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // Assume a "Cookie:nextjs=fast" header to be present on the incoming request
  // Getting cookies from the request using the `RequestCookies` API
  let cookie = request.cookies.get('nextjs')
  console.log(cookie) // => { name: 'nextjs', value: 'fast', Path: '/' }
  const allCookies = request.cookies.getAll()
  console.log(allCookies) // => [{ name: 'nextjs', value: 'fast' }]
 
  request.cookies.has('nextjs') // => true
  request.cookies.delete('nextjs')
  request.cookies.has('nextjs') // => false
 
 
}
```

how can I save my cookie on server side to then use cookie in server components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is [cookies](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies) function:

> Good to know: .set() is only available in a Server Action or Route
> Handler.

this is cookies function:

```
function cookies() {
    if ((0, _staticgenerationbailout.staticGenerationBailout)("cookies", {
        link: "https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/static-and-dynamic#dynamic-rendering"
    })) {
        return _requestcookies.RequestCookiesAdapter.seal(new _cookies.RequestCookies(new Headers({})));
    }
    const requestStore = _requestasyncstorage.requestAsyncStorage.getStore();
    if (!requestStore) {
        throw new Error("Invariant: cookies() expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available.");
    }
    const asyncActionStore = _actionasyncstorage.actionAsyncStorage.getStore();
    if (asyncActionStore && (asyncActionStore.isAction || asyncActionStore.isAppRoute)) {
        // We can't conditionally return different types here based on the context.
        // To avoid confusion, we always return the readonly type here.
        return requestStore.mutableCookies;
    }
    return requestStore.cookies;
}`
```

`requestStore.cookies` is `RequestCookies` class instance which is:

```
declare class RequestCookies {
    constructor(requestHeaders: Headers);
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[string, RequestCookie]>;
    /**
     * The amount of cookies received from the client
     */
    get size(): number;
    get(...args: [name: string] | [RequestCookie]): RequestCookie | undefined;
    getAll(...args: [name: string] | [RequestCookie] | []): RequestCookie[];
    has(name: string): boolean;
    set(...args: [key: string, value: string] | [options: RequestCookie]): this;
    /**
     * Delete the cookies matching the passed name or names in the request.
     */
    delete(
    /** Name or names of the cookies to be deleted  */
    names: string | string[]): boolean | boolean[];
    /**
     * Delete all the cookies in the cookies in the request.
     */
    clear(): this;
    toString(): string;
}
```

if you want to set it on middleware,

```
response.cookies.set(({
       name:"foo",
       value:"bar",
       path:"/"
}))
```

Comment: Can you explain in short how it works? (I mean function cookies() under the hood)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75895092/how-to-set-a-cookie-in-client-side-in-nextjs-13/75895152#75895152

Comment: cookies store the cookies in async storage. you can read about it asyn storage: https://dev.to/rexessilfie/using-asynclocalstorage-in-nextjs-44c8.

Comment: cookies are stoers in this async local storage. updated the answer

Comment: thank you very much, It was blowing my mind. Last question, is this "async local storage safe" and if I can use it if I set httpOnly cookie?