# JavaScript: How to use blob URL saved in localStorage after reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building an app in Next.js with no server. I get a video file input using an `<input>` tag, after that I convert it to a blob url and save it in `localStorage` for cross-session use.

However, after reloading the page the blob URL becomes invalid (at least that's what I think,) how can I use the blob after reload or is there an alternative ways?

**My Code:**

// convert file obj to blob url and save to localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('temp', URL.createObjectURL(data.file[0]))
```

// get video blob url and set it as videoRef src

```
const vidUrl = localStorage.getItem('temp')
videoRef.current.src = vidUrl;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75895092/how-to-set-a-cookie-in-client-side-in-nextjs-13

May this can help you, rather than storing in localstorage try with cookie.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using the built in blob url that the browser creates when you upload something on to the browser. This url is only temporarily when the browser keeps the file in memory and as soon as you refresh the page it will clear it, resulting in the url becoming invalid.

If you want to access the file later on, you will need to store it in a permanent storage. You can try to store it locally on your webserver if it allows for it or use a storage provider, like Blobstorage, S3 Buckets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `blob` is valid only for the duration of the browser session. Therefore, you can either store the `blob` data somewhere on the server, or you can convert the `blob` data to a `Base64` string and store this string in `localStorage`.